# "-" sign in svg path

Tags: html, svg

I try to learn drawing and animating with svg for using it in web. I met some examples of svg animation but I don't understand some parts of svg code. For example

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path fill="none" d="M300-10c0,0,0,164,0,410c0,232,0,410,0,410"/>
</svg>
```

I don't understand such part as M300-10. As I read in docs M means absolute moving to dot and we need to set X and Y coords

Another example

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 600 800" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path fill="none" d="M300-10c0,0,295,164,295,410c0,232-295,410-295,410"/>
</svg>
```

Same with "c0,232-295,410-295,410" - I don't understand, what means 232-295 and 410-295

I'll be grateful, if anybody explains me what does this means.

Answer (score 4):

A minus sign indicates a negative number.

```
M300-10
```

Move to x=300, y=-10

Comment: So, it's same as M 300, -10?